# Removing an item from ListBox while reading its value and Deleting it from the final price

Tags: vb.net

I have manged to delete an item from my list Box however i want it to:

read that specific item label and delete it from my final price

this is my code using Visual Basic:

```
Private Sub DeleteOrder_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DeleteOrder.Click

    OrderListBox.Items.Remove(OrderListBox.SelectedItem)

    Dim Value As Integer

    Value = OrderListBox.SelectedItem(Page3.Controls.Find("p3label" + CStr(1), True)(0).Text)

    Page3.MAX = Page3.MAX - Convert.ToDouble(Value)

    MessageBox.Show(Page3.MAX)

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, it is not clear what are you trying to do with the PROPERTY SelectedItem. In any case the Remove should be the last thing you do

Comment: will try and let you know, selected item (the one i selected with the mouse inside the box)

Comment: Not working Tried everything